# Can you help me match this grout?

Tags: tile, grout

Could someone help me match the grout that appears in the picture. I realize that many grouts have similar tones and that the picture is probably not accurate enough for identification but maybe you'll be able to give me some pointers.

I've gone to several tile shops in my area, and the closest I found was "River Rock" by Laticrete (https://laticrete.com/support-and-downloads/marketing-support/grout-selector) - however, my grout has a little bit of *peach* in it which I think comes through in the picture. I'm guessing this grout is about 9 years old.

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Comment: There's no way we'll get a good color match through your camera and our browsers.

Comment: Even if you had the original bag of grout it would look different due to age and different mixing conditions. It would help to have a white piece of paper behind the piece for proper color balance.

Comment: Bone? Buttercream? Alabaster? Go to your local bigbox store and borrow their color wheel, or their sample selection selector thing, or pamphlets, or just bring that chunk with you. However, I second Ed's comment : it ain't gonna match anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. If you read the Wikipedia article on [color balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance) you'll learn that it is actually quite difficult to maintain true color when capturing and displaying digital media.

For instance, the article has a pair of renderings of the same image of a lily:

[image: Lily images with different color balances]

The left image is as-shot by a digital camera; the right image is adjusted so that a gray surface in real life would appear as gray in the image. You'll see that the images are clearly different, but even that's too simple, as the author of the image couldn't account for your (or my) web browser and computer display, which will likely further tamper with the color rendering.

Your best bet is to continue working as you have been, and if you find no match close enough for your taste, figure out how to manufacture such a match by either blending different colors of grout or feathering the edges of the patch.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That said, on my mac, the color looks extraordinarily true.
In any case, perhaps someone could help me find grout that has a little bit of peach in it.

Comment: Unfortunately, [product recommendations are officially "off-topic"](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1175/why-are-product-recommendation-questions-globally-off-topic-in-diy-forum).